# Type Mismatch exception while Joining PairRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Spark 2.0.2 and Scala 2.11.8. I am trying to convert a text file into a Pair RDD and Join it with another Pair RDD. But when I try to Join them, I get type mismatch exception. Below is the code

```
val acc_ToSubAccIDKeyValPair = new PairRDDFunctions[String,String](sc.textFile(acc_ToSubAccID).map(x => x.split(",")).map(f=>(f(0),f(1)))) 

val acc_ToProductID = new PairRDDFunctions[String,String](retVal.flatMap(userToRating => userToRating._2).map(rating => (rating.user.toString,rating.product.toString)))

acc_ToSubAccIDKeyValPair.join(acc_ToProductID).values.saveAsTextFile(saveResultsPath)
```

The exception that I get after compiling:

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions[String,String]
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, ?)]
[error]     acc_ToSubAccIDKeyValPair.join(acc_ToProductID).values.saveAsTextFile(saveResultsPath)
[error]                                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

How can I Join these 2 RDD's?

I have tried the standard approach where RDD's get implicitly converted to Pair RDD's. But that approach gives me an exception in the runtime, when I try to run it on a hadoop cluster. Exception that I get is at the line where I join the RDD's is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.rddToPairRDDFunctions(Lorg/apache/spark/rdd/RDD;Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;Lscala/math/Ordering;)Lorg/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions;
```

Searching about this exception, people told me it could be a version mismatch exception, but my compile-time and runtime environments are same.
Thus, I tried to make Explicit PairRDD's.

Answer (score 1):

`join` expects an argument of type `RDD[(K, V)]`, not a `PairRDDFunctions`.

Generally speaking - you shouldn't explicitly instantiate `PairRDDFunctions` - Scala will implicitly convert the left-hand RDD to a `PairRDDFunctions`:

```
val acc_ToSubAccIDKeyValPair = sc.textFile(acc_ToSubAccID).map(x => x.split(",")).map(f=>(f(0),f(1)))

val acc_ToProductID = retVal.flatMap(userToRating => userToRating._2).map(rating => (rating.user.toString,rating.product.toString))

acc_ToSubAccIDKeyValPair.join(acc_ToProductID).values.saveAsTextFile(saveResultsPath)
```

Comment: Reason I had to do an explicit conversion because while I run the code given by you on a hadoop cluster, I get another type of exception, NoSuchMethodException on rddToPairRddFunctions, searching for it, people said, this could be due to version mismatch of spark in compile time and runtime environment, but that is not the case, in both environments Spark version is 2.0.2. Before downvoting at least ask, why are you trying something different?

Comment: @Adit: How do you know who down-voted your question? In my experience, it's unusual for someone to both answer *and* down-vote the question, and so likely it wasn't this user.  Please watch your language too.

Comment: First, the downvote isn't mine; Second, I attempted answering with the information you provided - which did not include the story you just told. Lastly, please, refrain from cursing the very people trying to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry your experience on SO made you assume people are here to chase something other then trying to improve the community we're a part of. Bottom line - you can try keeping the explicit instantiation for the first one and remove the second one. Should work. Good luck.

Comment: alright, I deleted the comment, but that ain't changing the fact that people here downvote for the sake of some brownie points.

Comment: @Adit: perhaps your misinformed comment had something to do with additional down-votes. Just consider the repercussion of your actions in the future.

Comment: @TzachZohar I am sorry my friend, I am just a little too exhausted with this problem of mine, I have tried what you just suggested too, but to no luck. I still get the NoSuchMethodException on rddToPairRDDFunctions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  I wish people were more helpful, unlike motivated to downvote and provide philosophy. Very much like you.

Comment: You're not doing yourself any favors blaming anyone for being unhelpful. @HovercraftFullOfEels is trying to help by showing how angry reactions just make things worse. Downvoting actually hurts the voter's reputation so that accusation is baseless. Your question seemed fine to me so I can't speak to why it was downvoted. Next time - please do include the "background" to give people like me the logic behind using this non-standard approach. As to the problem itself - sounds like a version mismatch indeed, can't say much more. Perhaps try posting a new question with all your build / setup info.

Comment: @TzachZohar I never downvoted a question/answer/comment, I have tried to be more accommodating always. Anyways, so I just followed the standard approach, just to reproduce the exception and present it here. This is the exception in runtime while trying to Join the RDD's:



      `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.rddToPairRDDFunctions(Lorg/apache/spark/rdd/RDD;Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;Lscala/math/Ordering;)Lorg/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions;`

Comment: @Adit _I never downvoted a question/answer/comment_ - looks like you missed some important ideas behind voting system. please read why [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and a number of discussions on meta, starting with [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/6910411).